# How to check and remove extra white spaces from a string during condition check

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, space

```
if (userResponseField.value.toUpperCase().includes('MY NAME IS ') === true || userResponseField.value.toUpperCase().includes('MY NAME\'S ') === true) {
```

What I am basically trying to do is create some sort of chatbot and it's working perfectly, it's just that it gets confused by extra whitespaces. How can I remove them during the condition check? I've looked for answers but none of them worked with the condition, they are still correct though, just not working with the way I want to do this whole thing. Note: I don't want the condition to make changes to the string/variable itself.

Comment: _just not working with the way I want to do this whole thing_ <= Be clear on how you want the all thing then ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex:

`if (userResponseField.value.match(/my\s+name(\s+i|')s/gi))`

This returns true for inputs such as `'   My       name     is  '`.

```js
let predicate = str => !!str.match(/my\s+name(\s+i|')s/gi);

[
  'my NaME    iS    ',
  'my NaME\'s',
  'my name s',
  'my ame is',
  'my nameis',
].forEach(input => console.log(input, ':', predicate(input)));
```

Comment: It's not working the way it should be. I have tried regex as well but it didn't do the job.

Comment: That's cool. You'll need to provide more details though if you're interested in help?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) :

```
if (
userResponseField.value.toUpperCase().trim().includes('MY NAME IS') === true ||
 userResponseField.value.toUpperCase().trim().includes('MY NAME\'S') === true
) {
```

Comment: Hi there! I have tried trim() already. Unfortunately, it's not doing what I want. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @PlamenDobrev `trim` does not mutate your original string

Comment: What I meant is that the bot still gets confused by these extra white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.trim()` on both the value and the hard-coded string:

```js
var userResponseField = {};
userResponseField.value = 'MY NAME IS';
if (userResponseField.value.toUpperCase().trim().includes('MY NAME IS '.trim()) === true || userResponseField.value.toUpperCase().trim().includes('MY NAME\'S '.trim()) === true) {
console.log("true");
}
```

Comment: Hi there! I have tried trim() already. Unfortunately, it's not doing what I want. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @PlamenDobrev did you use it on both of the comparisons?

Comment: Yes, I did. Even tried answering (the bot) in both ways. It didn't work. I still appreciate the help though.

Answer (score 0):

it's me again.
I found a clever way to do this and if some of you, in the future, have this problem and have just found this thread, here is how I solved my problem:

```
var userResponseFieldOutput = userResponseField.value;
userResponseField.value = userResponseField.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');if
```

Since this code, along with the condition I have posted above are stored in a function, the `userResponseFieldOutput` is what I am going to use for outputting the user's messages in the chatbox. It remains unedited, while the `userResponseField.value` has its spaces removed.

For example:

```
chatResponse(userResponseFieldOutput, "Hi, " + userName);
```

Ignore the `userName` variable, it is part of the code that doesn't have to be shown right now. This is another function I have made, the first value is what appears in the chat on the right side, where the user's responses are shown. The string and the variable after the comma are what appears on the left side of the chat, where the chatbot's messages are shown. But as you can see, I don't use `userResponseField.value`. Instead, I am using `userResponseFieldOutput`, which will print the user's output without the extra white spaces being removed.

I hope I have been useful to all of you who are looking for a solution to this problem.